# How can I clean the history of / remove duplicate commits from my master branch?

Tags: git, branch

I'm trying to clean up an old repository, which may well be the very first one I created when I was still learning how to use Git. Looking at the history of the `master`, I noticed this:

```
R -- P -- A -- B -- C -- D -- M -- E
      \                      /
       A' --- B' --- C' --- D'
```

Where `A'`, `B'`, ... are exactly the same commits as `A`, `B`,...
`M` is a merge commit and `E` isn't the last one.
There are two branches in my repository (`master` and `develop`), and `master` is the only affected(`develop` has been created later).

I would like to remove those duplicate commits, from `P` (exclusive) to `M`, resulting in something like this:

```
R -- P -- A -- B -- C -- D -- E
```

How could I achieve that?

Comment: Downvoters, the question is perfectly valid. Please consider reversing your vote, or at least elaborate on why you think the question deserves to be downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like M is a merge of a branch with a rebased version of the same branch

I would do the following:

```
git checkout master
git rebase --onto D M
```

This commands would rebase all commits from M to master branch tip over D (removing M from history), since A' - B' - C' - D' is reachable because of M, this commits will be "removed" from history and the history will end the way you are looking for:

> R--P-----A-----B----C----D----E

Rebase is a powerful command, you can do amazing things with it :)